# Estimating integrals using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

Let $f$ be a function such that $f''(x)<0$ for $x$ in $(0,1)$.

We are required to find $$\left\lfloor\left(\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{f(r/n)}{n}+ \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{f(r/n)}{n}}{2 \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx }\right)\right\rfloor$$ (i.e. the greatest integer function of this expression).

The answer given is $0$, which implies the numerator is less than the denominator.

My question is: how do we arrive at this answer?

I have two major concerns:

1. The denominator of the expression gives $2$ times the actual area under the curve,  whereas in the numerator: one of the sums will give an underestimate while the other an overestimate. How do I know about the extent of underestimation/overestimation? If the overestimation compensates for the underestimation we get the answer as $1$, otherwise $0$. Maybe the concavity of the function gives us the clue? I am not very well equipped with this idea.
2. Although it doesn't seem relevant to this particular question, but, as far as I know, to know which Riemann sum (left or right) gives the underestimate/overestimate, we need to know about whether the function is increasing or decreasing over the interval. This question, however, only gives us the concavity! And I am certain that a concave down function isn't necessarily decreasing.

Comment: Hi there. Reading your post, I can infer what your question(s) may be, but I think you could improve the post if you make your question very clear. Perhaps you could edit your question to say, after giving the expression, "The answer given is $0$. My question is: how do we arrive at this answer?". And *then* you can mention your concerns/thoughts.

Comment: @Shai, done, Thanks for the suggestion! Do you have any insight regarding the answer by the way? I am kind of desparate...

Comment: I'm having a little think, can't promise anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
  $$ \frac{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right) + \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} f\left( \frac{r}{n} \right)}{2} = \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\frac{f\left(\frac{r-1}{n}\right) + f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)}{2} $$
Now,
  $$ \frac{1}{n}\frac{f\left(\frac{r-1}{n}\right) + f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)}{2} $$
is the area of the trapezium formed by the vertices
  $$ \left( \frac{r-1}{n}, 0 \right), \left( \frac{r}{n}, 0 \right), \left( \frac{r}{n}, f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right) \right), \left( \frac{r-1}{n}, f\left(\frac{r-1}{n}\right) \right) $$
Crucially, the line connecting $\left( \frac{r-1}{n}, f\left(\frac{r-1}{n}\right) \right)$ to $\left( \frac{r}{n}, f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right) \right)$ lies completely beneath the curve, because the curve is concave. This means that the area, $T_{r}$, of this trapezium has area smaller than
  $$ \int_{\frac{r-1}{n}}^{\frac{r}{n}} f(x) \, dx $$
Therefore
  $$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} T_{r} \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \int_{\frac{r-1}{n}}^{\frac{r}{n}} f(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx $$
as required.

Comment: I believe you meant $f(r/n)$ in the first step instead of $f(r-1/n) $ twice

Comment: A Ctrl+v disaster! Fixed

Comment: [Trapezium rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) This might be of interest

Comment: although there is a sight issue. Consider for example f(x)=-x^2. This function lies below the x axis. Here, the area of the trapezium would be more than the integral. You can verify this by taking n=2, f(x)=-x^2. The result is coming out to be GIF[18/16]=1  :/

Comment: I totally agree - if the curve lies below the $x$ axis then the trapezium rule would cause the magnitude of the two sigmas to be greater than the magnitude of the integral, which is why when you divide them you get something $>1$. I actually forgot we were doing the floor and just focused on proving $\sigma + \sigma \leq 2\int$. We can only guarantee the floor is $0$ if we can assume $f>0$ on the interval.